# Regex - Pattern to Replace a HTML tag with specified attribute value

Tags: php, html, regex, replace, html-parsing

i'm using PHP and i want to check the following tags: *iframe* and *script*

I want that if they contains X value in the *src* attribute to add a Y class to the tag and change *src* attribute name to *data-src*.

ex.

```
$blacklist = array("google.com/plus.js", "google.com/drive.js");
$myclass = "blocked";

$html = '<script src="http://google.com/plus.js"></script>';

foreach($blacklist as $black)
{
    $html = preg_replace(...);
}

/* now $html must be: "<script data-src="google.com/plus.js" class="blocked"></script> */
```

Anyone can help me with this Regex operation?

Comment: I would recommend using a combination of [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php) and [XPath](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php) for this and not regex.

Also the answers to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18349130/how-parse-html-in-php) may help you

Comment: @sebastianForsberg, i think that 1 regex is fastest than DOMDocument

Comment: Well regex can be unreliable for HTML parsing, this depends on your needs and the type of input you are going to be passing to your script(s). 

See the answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7067426/load-time-is-it-quicker-to-parse-html-with-phps-domdocument-or-with-regular-ex) for more details...

Comment: Also, what have you tried so far? Your code snippet indicates you have not tried any regex patterns yet. If you haven't even attempted a regular expression that is where you should start if that is the route you are going to take. I have used [this tool](https://regex101.com/#pcre) in the past for regex testing.

Comment: @VasileAlexandruPeste it doesn't matter if regex are faster if they are incorrect. See http://htmlparsing.com/regexes.html for examples of why this problem is harder than you might originally suspect. Additionally, if you even make a regular expression robust enough to handle all these cases (and more) it very, very quickly becomes unmaintainable.

Answer (score 1):

I want to help.

To search with regex in the vim.
[image]

To search with regex in the vim.
[image]

To substitute with regex in the vim.
[image]